# How to show / hide loader in every service call in angular / ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic3, provider

I have a provider in which I have many functions is there any way to execute a function before any function call execution in ionic. 
here is my code and I want to execute a loader function before every HTTP call
in an easy manner without calling a function multiple times

```
 @Injectable()
  export class HttpProvider {
    BASEURL: string = 'https://www.ngrok.io';
    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
      console.log('Hello HttpProvider Provider');
    }

    getCustomerInfo(customer_mobile) {
      return this.http.post(this.BASEURL + '/customer/get', {
        customer_mobile,
      });
    }

    addNewCustomer(customerInfo) {
      return this.http.post(this.BASEURL + '/customer/save', customerInfo);
    }
    updateCustomer(customerInfo) {
      return this.http.post(this.BASEURL + '/customer/update', customerInfo);
    }

    getVendorList(filterObject) {
      return this.http.post(this.BASEURL + '/getvendorlist', filterObject);
    }

    getVendorInfo(vendor_id) {
      return this.http.post(this.BASEURL + '/getvendorinfo', {
        vendor_id,
      });
    }

    updateAddress(updatedAddress) {
      return this.http.post(
        this.BASEURL + '/customeraddress/update',
        updatedAddress
      );
    }
    addAddress(newAddress) {
      return this.http.post(this.BASEURL + '/customeraddress/save', newAddress);
    }

    addOrder(orderDetails) {
      return this.http.post(this.BASEURL + '/order/save', orderDetails);
    }

    deleteAddress(address_id) {
      return this.http.post(this.BASEURL + '/customeraddress/delete', {
        address_id,
      });
    }
    getOrderList(customer_id, date?) {
      return this.http.post(
        this.BASEURL + '/fetchallcustomerorders',
        requestBody
      );
    }
    addReview(review: { feedback: string; rating: string; order_id: string }) {
      return this.http.post(this.BASEURL + '/orderreview', review);
    }


  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`HTTPInterceptors`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) to show / hide loader on every service call.

This tutorial will help you to achieve this: [Show Loader on every service call in angular](https://medium.com/@johnmeguira/intercept-all-http-calls-with-angular-5-to-display-a-loader-281924b73ad8)

You can show the loader inside the `intercept` method, once the response came you can hide it.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) { }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    this.loaderService.show();

    return next
        .handle(req)
        .do(event => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {

                this.loaderService.hide();
            }
        });
  }
```

Comment: are they supported in angular 4?

Comment: Yes, it's supported since Angular 4.3.4

Comment: ok but the tutorial you provide only trigger when request is completed i want it when it initialize

Comment: I have updated my answer with some code for you to show / hide loader